# Calculate Timeout Value to Time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have script that I kill using the `timeout` command. Right now I set a timeout value by hand so that it stops before 9 AM. I am trying to come up with a `bash` command using `date` that will when run calculate how many hours left till 9 AM. I can't find the syntax for `date -d next 09:00`, command may run before 9AM same day or after 9AM so it runs till next day?

Comment: The `at` utility is designed to do just this. `echo "some command" | at 9:00AM` will run `some command` at the next 9am, today or tomorrow, whichever comes first. Make sure it saves its output to a file if you want to see it.

Comment: Similar question was answered here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245751/date-getting-next-certain-hour  does this solution is ok for you ?

Comment: @joanis I will trigger this from systemd. I thought `at` will block systemd till 9AM.

Comment: Good question, I only tested this on an interactive shell, I don't know whether it'll interact with systemd.

Comment: Why did the answer get deleted? I thought it was helpful, even if not quite complete yet!

Comment: I've deleted my answer since OP notices he didn't want to rely on 'tomorrow' since that won't work when called between 09 - 12am. Paul's linked post does the same idea. Would you like for me to undelete the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer, for my original answer, please check the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67722665/timeline) and [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722159/calcualte-timeout-value-to-time#comment119703282_67722665).

---

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245751/date-getting-next-certain-hour) linked post, lets add some logic to check the next 09AM is today, or tomorrow to get the desired output:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Current hour
H=$(date +%-H)

# If today is before 9am
# Set target to 'upcoming 9am'
# Otherwise, set to 'tomorrow 9'
(( $H < 9 )) && target=$(date -d '9' '+%s') || target=$(date -d 'tomorrow 9' '+%s')

# Get diffs in hours
current=$(date +%s)
hours=$(((target - current) / 60 / 60))

# Result
echo "Current GMT Time: $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"
echo "$hours hours until tomorrow 09:00:00"
```

```
Current GMT Time: 2021-05-27 13:20
19 hours until tomorrow 09:00:00
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDNa8MgHL37V7ylsUa6kJwGCe1ph2aHMth62TEfphGaONRQBv3fM5PabYeBKPre731YlaabptVDUskhqdyFkBWeR63FYNGpUZNiF0ZNaQU2NC74DL@0sKopvyANKtEqLZCVvQPehYUt9Wk@FNj4WateDqcZZQ5@tZ3QF2nEI4ynWNUrrdUFGSNRhLDAFhk4x3rtle7ucQOWMbANNYzjev0H/iPmeXPavbNqZNsayGFpZEh96/dbzHCyIO4linyDGJ7GkeApXTa@KL4JM54tEXWnENz/an844ih7kcOrugQfMe1j2oAWOT0wHviRcPG6ZcE4WHnGT/Q0y9PUrWCavgE)

Comment: I did not want to use `tomorrow` cause if the command is triggered after 12AM, 9AM tomorrow will be the other day no?

Comment: Ahh then I'd use the solution linked by Paul, same idea, but checks if it's between12am and 9am.

Comment: Updated to `date +%-H` to prevent field padding. Thx for pointing this out.\

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner worked for me to return seconds -

```
echo $(( $(date +%s -d "9am tomorrow") - $(date +%s) ))
```

so you could use that value for a `sleep`, and it's pretty easy to calculate hours/minutes/seconds with modulo division if you need it.

At 2021-05-27,08:15:53 -

```
$: secsTill9amTomorrow=$(( $(date +%s -d "9am tomorrow") - $(date +%s) ))
$: echo $secsTill9amTomorrow
88814
$: hrsAsSecs=$((  secsTill9amTomorrow - ( secsTill9amTomorrow % 3600 ) ))
$: echo $hrsAsSecs
86400
$: hrsTo9=$(( hrsAsSecs / 3600 ))
$: echo $hrsTo9
24
$: minsAsSecs=$(( secsTill9amTomorrow - hrsAsSecs ))
$: echo $minsAsSecs
2414
$: mins=$(( minsAsSecs / 60 ))
$: echo $mins
40
$: secs=$(( minsAsSecs % 60 ))
$: echo $secs
14
$: echo "H:M:S - $hrsTo9:$mins:$secs"
H:M:S - 24:40:14
```